# Find n closest non-NA values to position t in vector

Tags: r, vector, closest

This is probably a simple question for those experienced in R, but it is something that I (a novice) am struggling with...

I have two examples of vectors that are common to the problem I am trying to solve, `A` and `B`:

```
A <- c(1,3,NA,3,NA,4,NA,1,7,NA,2,NA,9,9,10)
B <- c(1,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,9)

#and three scalars
R <- 4
t <- 5
N <- 3
```

There is a fourth scalar, `n`, where `0<=n<=N`.  In general, `N <= R`.

I want to find the `n` closest non-`NA` values to `t` such that they fall within a radius `R` centered on `t`.  I.e., the search radius, `R` comprises of `R+1` values.  For example A, the search radius sequence is `(3,NA,3,NA,4,NA,1)`, where `t=NA`, the middle value in the search radius sequence.

The expected answer can be one of two results for A:

```
answerA1 <- c(3,4,1)
```

OR

```
answerA2 <- c(3,4,3)
```

The expected answer for B:

```
answerB <- c(1,3)
```

How would I accomplish this task in the most time- and space-efficient manner?  One liners, loops, etc. are welcome.  If I have to choose a preference, it is for speed!

Thanks in advance!

Note:

For this case, I understand that the third closest non-`NA` value may involve choosing a preference for the third value to fall on either the right or left of `t` (as shown by the two possible answers above).  I do not have a preference for whether this values falls to the left or the right of `t` but, if there is a way to leave it to random chance, (whether the third value falls to the right or the left) that would be ideal (but, again, it is not a requirement).

Comment: Not clear what `c(3,4,1)` is. Is it `c(R,t,n)`? If so, why is `c(3,4,3)` as good as `c(3,4,1)`?

Comment: Clarified by providing another example and expected answer.  I am looking for the `n` closest non-NA values to index `t`.  In general, `0<=n<=N`.  For example A, both c(3,4,3) and c(3,4,1) are equally as good answers because they are both the three closest non-NA values within the search radius, `R` centered on `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relatively short solution is:

```
orderedA <- A[order(abs(seq_len(length(A)) - t))][seq_len(R*2)]
n_obj <- min(sum(is.na(orderedA)), N, length(na.omit(orderedA)))
res <- na.omit(orderedA)[seq_len(n_obj)]

res
#[1] 3 4 3
```

Breaking this down a little more the steps are:

1. Order A, by the absolute distance from the position of interest, `t`.

   - **Code is**: `A[order(abs(seq_len(length(A)) - t))]`
2. Subset to the first `R*2` elements (so this will get the elements on either side of `t` within `R`.

   - **Code is:** `[seq_len(R*2)]`
3. Get the first `min(N, # of non-NA, len of non-NA)` elements

   - **Code is:** `min(sum(is.na(orderedA)), N, length(na.omit(orderedA)))`
4. Drop `NA`

   - **Code is:** `na.omit()`
5. Take first elements determined in step 3 (whichever is smaller)

   - **Code is:** `[seq_len(n_obj)]`

Comment: Thanks @Mike H.!  What if we wanted to generalize this such that `0<=n<=N`?  Where N is given as the argument (i.e., instead of a fixed `n`)?  In general, `N<=R`.

Comment: @thatWaterGuy, Can you elaborate a little more on what you mean? Do you want to pass `N` as an arugment, and then `n` is determined randomly such that `0<=n<=N`?

Comment: `n` is determined by the number of non-NA elements within the search radius `R` centered on `t`, limited by an upper value of `N`, hence `0<=n<=N`.  See example B in my edited question.  I want to return at most `N` non-`NA` values within the search radius, but sometimes there are less than `N` non-`NA` values, this is what `n` represents.

Comment: @thatWaterGuy, See my update - is that what you want? The last part was changed to select the first `min(N, # of NA)` elements

Comment: thanks for your time. For...

`> B <- c(1,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,9)

> orderedB <- B[order(abs(seq_len(length(B)) - 5))][seq_len(4*2)]

> ansB <- na.omit(orderedB)[seq_len(min(sum(is.na(orderedB)), 3))]`

It returns:

`# [1]  3  1 NA`

It should be:

`[1]  3  1`

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I'll update - should just need to add another condition to the `min()`. @thatWaterGuy see my edits - this should give you what you want now for `A` and `B`. At this point, I'd recommend breaking out the code since there are a lot of nested functions

Comment: that's it!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147111/discussion-between-thatwaterguy-and-mike-h).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
thingfinder <- function(A,R,t,n) {
  left <- A[t:(t-R-1)]
  right <- A[t:(t+R+1)]
  leftrightmat <- cbind(left,right)
  raw_ans <- as.vector(t(leftrightmat))
  ans <- raw_ans[!is.na(raw_ans)]
  return(ans[1:n])
}

thingfinder(A=c(1,3,NA,3,NA,4,NA,1,7,NA,2,NA,9,9,10), R=3, t=5, n=3)
##  [1] 3 4 3
```

This would give priority to the left side, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful to others, @Mike H. also provided me with a solution to return the index `positions` associated with the desired vector elements `res`:

`A <- setNames(A, seq_len(length(A)))`

`orderedA <- A[order(abs(seq_len(length(A)) - t))][seq_len(R*2)]`

`n_obj <- min(sum(is.na(orderedA)), N, length(na.omit(orderedA)))`

`res <- na.omit(orderedA)[seq_len(n_obj)]`

`positions <- as.numeric(names(res))`